# Export Maven dependencies and maintain repository folder structure

Tags: maven, maven-3, maven-dependency-plugin

I'm trying to know whether it's possible to export/copy dependencies of a project managed using Maven while maintaining the folder structure that is adopted in the local repository.

*The root of my need* is that I have amassed through almost ten years a lot of artifacts in my local repository (~8GB). I am no longer working on those old projects from previous assignments that drew most of the artifacts in and now, I need to move just what is needed for one single project (~650MB of artifacts) to a different computer. I can't just set the other computer to download artifacts again because many of these artifacts were retrieved from a local Nexus proxy in previous assignments. Moreover, I don't have the source code for these artifacts so I can't just install them.

`dependency:copy-dependencies` doesn't do the trick because all artifacts are simply dumped in a single folder, instead of having say `.m2\repository\mysql\mysql-connector-java\5.1.38\mysql-connector-java-5.1.38.jar`

I believe my question can also be rephrased as “How can I extract from my local Maven repository a subset of the repository that is related to only one specific project?”

Comment: Do you have all required artifacts in local Nexus proxy?

Comment: (you don't need source code to install a dependency, `install-file` will work just fine without)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can actually use the [Maven Dependency Plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/) and its `copy-dependencies` goal, as you mentioned.

What you actually missed is its [`useRepositoryLayout`](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/copy-dependencies-mojo.html#useRepositoryLayout) option

> Place each artifact in the same directory layout as a default repository.
>   example: /outputDirectory/junit/junit/3.8.1/junit-3.8.1.jar.
>
> - **Type**: boolean.
> - **Since**: 2.0-alpha-2.
> - **Required**: No.
> - **User Property**: mdep.useRepositoryLayout.
> - **Default**: false.

You could hence execute - as an example - the following:

```
mvn dependency:copy-dependencies -Dmdep.useRepositoryLayout=true \
    -DoutputDirectory=.m2/repository
```

Answer (score 0):

If you missing some dependency, then download that dependencies from other source and paste it in your .m2(maven local repository ) folder.